# performance for sum oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, aggregate-functions

I have to sum a huge number of data with aggregation and where clause, using this query
what I am doing is like this : I have three tables one contains terms the second contains user terms , and the third contains correlation factor between term and user term.
I want to calculate the similarity between the sentence that that user inserted with an already existing sentences, and take the results greater than .5 by summing the correlation factor between sentences' terms
The problem is that this query takes more than 15 min. because I have huge tables
any suggestions to improve performance please?

```
     insert into PLAG_SENTENCE_SIMILARITY
     SELECT  plag_TERMS.SENTENCE_ID ,plag_User_TERMS.SENTENCE_ID,
      least(  sum( plag_TERM_CORRELATIONS3.CORRELATION_FACTOR)/ plag_terms.sentence_length,
      sum (plag_TERM_CORRELATIONS3.CORRELATION_FACTOR)/ plag_user_terms.sentence_length),
      plag_TERMs.isn,
      plag_user_terms.isn 
    FROM plag_TERM_CORRELATIONS3,
    plag_TERMS,
    Plag_User_TERMS
   WHERE ( Plag_TERMS.TERM_ROOT  = Plag_TERM_CORRELATIONS3.TERM1
   AND Plag_User_TERMS.TERM_ROOT = Plag_TERM_CORRELATIONS3.TERM2 
   AND Plag_User_Terms.ISN=123)
   having 
    least(  sum( plag_TERM_CORRELATIONS3.CORRELATION_FACTOR)/ plag_terms.sentence_length,
      sum (plag_TERM_CORRELATIONS3.CORRELATION_FACTOR)/ plag_user_terms.sentence_length) >0.5
      group by (plag_User_TERMS.SENTENCE_ID,plag_TERMS.SENTENCE_ID ,  plag_TERMs.isn,       plag_terms.sentence_length,plag_user_terms.sentence_length, plag_user_terms.isn);
```

plag_terms contains more than 50 million records and plag_correlations3 contains 500000

Comment: we'd need to see execution plans to begin to isolate the performance.  At a minimum indexes would seem appropriate on PLAG_TERMS.Term_Root, Plag_Term_Correlations3.term1, term2 and plag_user_Terms.isn.  So what indexes exist presently? on Plag_Term_correlations3, plag_terms, and plag_user_terms?

Comment: thanks xQbert, plag_terms has index on term_root , plag_user_terms has index on term_root, plag_correlations2 has index on term1,term2,correlation_factor

Comment: Please make your information consistent across your whole question. In your query, you refer to `plag_term_correlations3`, `plag_terms` and `plag_user_terms`. Below your query you refer to `plag_correlations4` not used anywhere else. In your recent comment you refer to indexes on `plag_correlations2`, which you are not using anywhere else.

Comment: Also, please, post here the row counts for `plag_term_correlations`, `plag_terms`, `plag_user_terms` and `plag_user_terms` for `isn = 123`. Also, please post here complete information on primary keys on the tables in use, plus complete information on foreign keys between the tables in use. Also, please, post here the execution plan of your query.

Comment: ok, thanks @nop77svk just mistyping, Its plag_terms_correlation4,

Comment: all the tables have an ID as pk, Its autonumber, no foreign keys , Plag_term_correlations4 has 500000 records, plag_terms has more than 50 million terms, plag_user_terms is about 10000 terms, I tried to insert the execution plan here as image, but i don't know how

Comment: Generate an explain plan by running `explain plan for insert ...`, then get the explain plan with `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  The default text format is much more helpful than an image.

Comment: @JonHeller thank you. here is the link to an image of my explain plan https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmblbtg0rrio5o7/explain%20Plan.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Can I use another technique to insert data? I think the insert statement takes much time

Comment: The select statement returns 738 rows only.....

Comment: The insert itself is not an issue, since it writes only 738 rows. The select needs tuneup. Will try and come up with a solution, but it may take a few days, considering my current time reserves.

Comment: @nop77svk ,thank you, I appreciate you efforts

Comment: @nop77svk any help please? I need the solution asap. thanks

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have enough free time for stackoverfliw.com anymore.

Comment: Moreover, I asked you for the execution plan, yet you provided none. There's no query tuning without execution plans.

Comment: @nop77svk thanks for you effort, I already added the execution plan in one of the comments above, since I have no enough reputations I added the image to dropbox and here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmblbtg0rrio5o7/explain%20Plan.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Can ORACLE TEXT help me in solving my problem ? what i need is to check similarity between 2 sentences, My corpus contains millions of sentences and i want to check if the user document is similar to one or more of them using correlation factor..by comparing term by term.. this is my original problem.. if needed i will explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sufficient amount of free disk space, then create a materialized view

- over the join of the three tables
- fast-refreshable on commit (don't use the ANSI join syntax here, even if tempted to do so, or the mview won't be fast-refreshable ... a strange bug in Oracle)
- with query rewrite enabled
- properly physically organized for quick calculations

The query rewrite is optional. If you can modify the above `insert-select`, then you can just select from the materialized view instead of selecting from the join of the three tables.

As for the physical organization, consider

- hash partitioning by `Plag_User_Terms.ISN` (with a sufficiently high number of partitions; don't hesitate to partition your table with e.g. 1024 partitions, if it seems reasonable) if you want to do a bulk calculation over all values of `ISN`
- single-table hash clustering by `Plag_User_Terms.ISN` if you want to retain your calculation over a single `ISN`

If you don't have a spare disk space, then just hint your query to

- either use nested loops joins, since the number of rows processed seems to be quite low (assumed by the estimations in the execution plan)
- or full-scan the `plag_correlations3` table in parallel

*Bottom line:* Constrain your tables with foreign keys, check constraints, not-null constraints, unique constraints, everything! Because Oracle optimizer is capable of using most of these informations to its advantage, as are the people who tune SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks @nop77svk .. I created indexes and I have this execution plan https://www.dropbox.com/s/rumiukl199xa839/execution%20plan_1.PNG?dl=0

Comment: But you told us (on Nov 11) that you already had indexes on those columns! :-( Are you joking on us?

Comment: absolutely NO.. why should I do so? look at the first execution plan.. there were indexes.. but I read many article on the web.. and deleted indexes and recreated them..I reordered index columns.. I did many many trials.. I don't know why the execution plan changed.. I Swear .. I don't Know.. just playing a round many solutions.. this occurred.. Please don't misunderstand it.. I need the solution.. If you can help ..you are doing a charity.. thanks

Comment: I accepted your answer although I didn't try it yet..@nop77svk